# How to get the value of a textarea in Symfony

Tags: symfony1

I can't seem to get the inputted text of a textarea.  When I do :

```
die($request->getPostParameter('comment'))
```

It outputs the word "array".  When I `print_r()` it does show the textarea is an array and its value is stored in the array.  But I don't know how to get that value so I can put it into a field in a table.

@greg0ire:  I am doing this because I am trying to save data to two different tables.  My html page displays a form that is actually made up of two forms from two different classes/models.  I have managed to save all fields to both tables except for the comment field.  I then tried getting the value and realising it was an array, wondered if this was what was causing my data not to save.  This is why I am asking this question.  I have asked another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961527/how-to-update-2-tables-from-one-form-in-symfony) which explains the context.

These are the functions that run on clicking the submit button

```
   public function executeUpdateInlineForm(sfWebRequest $request)
{

  $overdueInvestigation = Doctrine_Core::getTable('investigation')->find( $request->getParameter('id'));

    $investigationForm = new investigationInlineForm($overdueInvestigation);
    $commentForm=new commentForm();


    $investigationForm->bind($request->getParameter($investigationForm->getName()), $request->getFiles($investigationForm->getName()));
    $commentForm->bind($request->getParameter($commentForm->getName()), $request->getFiles($commentForm->getName()));

    $this->processInlineForm($investigationForm, $commentForm);

  }

protected function processInlineForm(sfForm $investigationForm, sfForm $commentForm)
{

   if ($investigationForm->isValid())
      {
         $investigation = $investigationForm->save();  

         $comment = $commentForm->updateObject();
         $comment->setInvestigation_id($investigationForm->getObject()->getId());
         $comment->setComment($commentForm->getObject()->getComment());
         $comment->setuserId($investigationForm->getObject()->getCreatedUserId());
         $comment->setDateEntered(time());
         $comment->save();
         $this->redirect('investigation/overdue/');
     }


}
```

Comment: Why mark my question down? It may seem easy to someone who knows symfony and php, but I don't!

Comment: +1 to balance unjustified downvote

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update 2 tables from one form in Symfony?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961527/how-to-update-2-tables-from-one-form-in-symfony)

Comment: I vote to close this question as duplicate of the first one so that they get merged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could simply store `$request->getPostParameter('comment')` in an array and use `array_pop()` on this array, but I think it would be better to understand why you're getting an array. I think the name of the textarea must be `comment[]`, when it should probably be just `comment`.

**UPDATE**

After reading your update and your other question it seems you need to have this naming convention for your fields:

```
<input type="text" name="investigation[field1]"/>
<input type="text" name="investigation[field2]"/>
<input type="text" name="investigation[field3]"/>
<input type="text" name="comment[content]"/>
```

Use the `setNameFormat()` method on the widget schema of your forms to achieve this, then bind your investigation form to the `investigation` request parameter, and your comment form to the `comment` parameter and you will be fine.

Good luck!

Comment: @greg I thanks for your input, I have updated my question above to make it clearer rather than adding a comment with code in it.

Comment: Thanks.  I have managed to change the nameFormat of the comment field do it's name is just 'comment'.  I can now get the value fine.  My problem is now that when I am trying to bind the request to $comment I get this error:  Warning: array_key_exists() [function.array-key-exists]: The first argument should be either a string or an integer in C:\xampp\htdocs\tracking\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\util\sfParameterHolder.class.php on line 53

Comment: It seems that $request->getParameter($commentForm->getName() is not returning anything, therefore my bind function isn't getting one of two paramters (probably isn't getting the second either).

Comment: look at the code of the getName() method: it expects the name format to contain "[%s]". Your form nameFormat should be comment[%s], not just comment (%s will contain a field name).

Comment: Ok, but that is what it was to begin with.  Above, you said "the name of the textarea must be comment[], when it should probably be just comment".  Before comment was comment['comment'], that was the problem, it was an array so I couldn't get the value.  I've bene working on it this morning though and decided to do it the way I will find easiest, which is just adding it to an array and using array_pop like you say above.  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Nicola: Glad you made it, and sorry the update is incoherent with the original answer